# python setup.py to install multiple modules

Tags: python, python-2.6

Below is my setup.py code :

```
from os import path
import sys
python_version = sys.version_info[:2]

if python_version < (2, 6):
    raise Exception("This version of xlrd requires Python 2.6 or above. "
                "For older versions of Python, you can use the 0.8 series.")

av = sys.argv
if len(av) > 1 and av[1].lower() == "--egg":
    del av[1]
    from setuptools import setup
else:
    from distutils.core import setup

from xlrd.xlrd.info import __VERSION__ as p
from xlwt.xlwt import __VERSION__

DESCRIPTION = (
    'Library to create spreadsheet files compatible with '
     'MS Excel 97/2000/XP/2003 XLS files, '
     'on any platform, with Python 2.3 to 2.7'
     )



CLASSIFIERS = [
    'Operating System :: OS Independent',
    'Programming Language :: Python',
    'License :: OSI Approved :: BSD License',
    'Development Status :: 5 - Production/Stable',
    'Intended Audience :: Developers',
    'Topic :: Software Development :: Libraries :: Python Modules',
    'Topic :: Office/Business :: Financial :: Spreadsheet',
    'Topic :: Database',
    'Topic :: Internet :: WWW/HTTP :: Dynamic Content :: CGI Tools/Libraries',
    ]

KEYWORDS = (
    'xls excel spreadsheet workbook worksheet pyExcelerator'
    )
setup(
    name = 'xlrd',
    version = p,
    author = 'John Machin',
    author_email = 'sjmachin@lexicon.net',
    url = 'http://www.python-excel.org/',
    packages = ['xlrd'],
    scripts = [
        'xlrd/scripts/runxlrd.py',
         ],
    package_data={
        'xlrd/xlrd': [
            'doc/*.htm*',
            # 'doc/*.txt',
            'examples/*.*',
            ],

        },

keywords = ['xls', 'excel', 'spreadsheet', 'workbook'],
classifiers = [
        'Development Status :: 5 - Production/Stable',
        'Intended Audience :: Developers',
        'License :: OSI Approved :: BSD License',
        'Programming Language :: Python',
        'Programming Language :: Python :: 2',
        'Programming Language :: Python :: 3',
        'Operating System :: OS Independent',
        'Topic :: Database',
        'Topic :: Office/Business',
        'Topic :: Software Development :: Libraries :: Python Modules',
        ],

)
setup (
    name = 'xlwt',
    version = __VERSION__,
    maintainer = 'John Machin',
    maintainer_email = 'sjmachin@lexicon.net',
    url = 'http://www.python-excel.org/',
    download_url = 'http://pypi.python.org/pypi/xlwt',
    description = DESCRIPTION,
    long_description = LONG_DESCRIPTION,
    license = 'BSD',
    platforms = 'Platform Independent',
    packages = ['xlwt'],
    keywords = KEYWORDS,
    classifiers = CLASSIFIERS,
    package_data = {
        'xlwt/xlwt': [
            'doc/*.*',
            'examples/*.*',
            'tests/*.*',
            ],
        },
       )
```

I have tried to marge `setup.py` of both `xlrd` and `xlwt` here and trying to run master `setup.py` to install both the modules at one shot. It is installing the modules but not the attributes so can't use those modules. Basically my need is to run a single script and install multiple modules in clients machine. Is is possible? Please guide me if ay other way I can do this . Thanks in advance.

Comment: Which attributes are you talking about?

Comment: @BasicWolf i am trying to run the script                        `import xlrd
workbook = xlrd.open_workbook('my_workbook.xls')` it is throwing the error `AttributeError: 'module' object has no attribute 'open_workbook' `

Comment: Allright, it means that you can at least import the xlrd module. What does `dir(xlrd)` print out?

Comment: it is printing `['__builtins__', '__doc__', '__file__', '__name__', '__package__', '__path__']`

Comment: Hm.. What is the setup system are you using? Is it setuptools? distribute? distutils? Because I can't see any import which shows that.

Comment: @BasicWolf I am using `distutils` . Is it a right approach to install multiple modules through a single setup.py. Actually I am trying this on my own , so not sure is it right way or wrong. Can you guide me if any other way exists that through a single script I can install multiple dependent modules used in my application while installing the application in another machine.

Comment: Well, I've never done that through a single setup.py script. A straightforward way would be simply making a shell script which invokes setup.py of each package separately.

Comment: @BasicWolf it will be very helpful if you can give me a short code snippet of it. Also then i have to make `batch` file for windows right?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

As an example of invoking setup.py of both packages. Let's consider that you are in a some top level directory with the following structure:

```
mydir
|
|--setup.sh # global setup script
|
|--xlrd
|  |
|  |--...
|  |--setup.py
|  |--...
|
|--xlwt
   |
   |--...
   |--setup.py
   |--...
```

A shell script is simple:

```
#!/bin/sh
python ./xlrd/setup.py install
python ./xlwt/setup.py install
```

A batch script should be pretty similar:

```
xlrd\setup.py install
xlwt\setup.py install
```