# Multiple subpackages within one package

Tags: python, package, setuptools, setup.py

I am trying to write a package with the following structure

```
/package
    setup.py

    /subpackage1
        subpackage1.py
        __init__.py
    /subpackage2
        subpackage2.py
        __init__.py
        /utils
            some_other_files_and_codes
            __init__.py
```

My setup.py currently looks like this:

```
from setuptools import setup, find_packages

setup(
        name = 'subpackage1',
        version = '1.0',
        install_requires=['numpy', 
                          'scipy'],
        packages = find_packages(),                       
      )
```

I then install it using pip `install -e .` from the `/package` folder.
However, I am not able to import subpackage2, only subpackage1.

I would like to be able to import them as

```
from package import subpackage1
from package import subpackage2
```

This is important because subpackage1 and subpackage2 exist as standalone packages too on my system.

Could someone help me with this?

Comment: Does this answer your question? https://stackoverflow.com/questions/19806510/python-setup-py-to-install-multiple-modules

Comment: Does it mean that I need to have setup.py in both subfolders? How would I ensure that subpackage1 and subpackage2 are both part of same module?

Answer (score 2):

The snippets you are showing do not make sense. Looks like there's a misunderstanding, in particular there's probably confusion between the name of the Python project and the names of the top-level importable packages.

In the `setuptools.setup()` function call, the parameter to the `name` argument should be the name of the project, not the name of an importable top level package. They can be the same names, but not necessarily.

The following might make it more explicit:

```
MyPythonProject
├── my_importable_package_one
│   ├── __init__.py
│   └── my_module_foo.py
├── my_importable_package_two
│   ├── __init__.py
│   └── my_module_bar.py
└── setup.py
```

`setup.py`

```
import setuptools
setuptools.setup(
    name='MyPythonProject',
    version='1.2.3',
    packages=['my_importable_package_one', 'my_importable_package_two'],
    # ...
)
```

```
from my_importable_package_one import my_module_foo
from my_importable_package_two import my_module_bar
```

Maybe this [article on the terminology of Python packaging](https://sinoroc.gitlab.io/kb/python/packaging.html) might help.

Comment: Thank you, this makes sense. However, I have already a package called my_importable_package_one on my system. How can I ensure that it is called as a part of MyPythonProject? I want to import it as from MyPythonProject import my_importable_package_one or something equivalent that distinguishes it from the standalone version.

Comment: Short answer: you can't. Long answer: anything is possible, it will most likely require way too much work for very little gain. There's a similar question with no answer here: https://stackoverflow.com/q/59051935/11138259